# How to debug exeptions thrown in rebus handlers?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rebus

What is the recommended way do debug exceptions during development in localhost being throws in handlers like this:

```
class MyEventHandler : IHandleMessages<MyEvent>
{
    public async Task Handle(BlogLinkCreated message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        throw new Exception();
    } 
}
```

I see some exceptions in the debug output, but I don't know from where they came. I want to see stacktrace and ideally step trough callstack and see local variables' values.

Comment: I sometimes add a msgbox in where the exception is occurring then use Cntrl-Break to get code to stop exception.  Then hit OK buttom on message box.

Comment: But I don't know where exception is occurring

Comment: Add a try/catch instead of the throw and put message box in the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Rebus logs exceptions caught when executing handlers, including everything that the exceptions reveal about themselves by calling `.ToString()` on them.

This includes the full stack trace, and if you're running a Debug build of your code, it will also include source file line numbers.

It should be pretty easy – provided that you haven't disabled logging somehow – to figure out which line of code throws any exception that bubbles out for Rebus to see.

If you're using Visual Studio to develop your code, you can also just hit F5 (or whichever hotkey you're using to launch your app with the debugger attached) and then wait until the debugger breaks on the exception.

Comment: Ok, I've noticed that it logs to console by default, now I need to figure out how to log it using ILogger. However it never breaks the debugging session in Visual Studio.
Also, I have notices, that when first handler fails, the other handlers are never invoked. is this by purpose?

Comment: You can easily replicate the scenario, by modifying your[ServiceProvide/Sample.ConsolleApp](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.ServiceProvider/blob/master/Sample.ConsoleApp/Handler1.cs) to include handler that does throw

Comment: What is `ILogger`? Are you using Serilog? In that case you can simply import the [Rebus.Serilog](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Serilog) package

Comment: No, it is .net core's buildin [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger)

Comment: ok, try [this Rebus logging package then](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) ;)